# How can I get Adobe Extension Manager application path from registry through Inno Setup?

Tags: windows, registry, inno-setup

I have been looking to develop an installer that installs my extension through Inno Setup. I want to launch the Adobe Extension Manager as a post install process in the [Run] section of the Inno Setup install process. Now, there can be multiple versions of Extension Manager installed on a machine, the latest version of Extension Manager is launched by default. I want to make sure that the product version chosen by the user during installation launches the corresponding Extension Manager. Eg., if a machine has Photoshop CS5, CS6 installed, and the user chooses Photoshop CS5, then the Extension Manager CS5 should be launched. For this I want the path to the application. I am unable to get the Extension Manager path from the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

I was able to get the path of Extension Manager by the following,

```
RegQueryStringValue(HKCR, 'Applications\Adobe Extension Manager CS5.exe\shell\open\command', '', path);
```

where path is the output string.

Thanks!